# Alignment of text within a table with color

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Is it possible to align the numbers in the last column of a table with color? For this column, I would like the numbers (they are actually text) to be in the center of the table, but aligned to the right of last number. I was able to align them using the siunitx package, but the color and last vertical line were gone. Is there an easy way to do keep the color/vertical line and align the text? Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,colortbl}

\definecolor{LightDandelion}{RGB}{255,255,204}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{LightDandelion}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}


{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%

\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{table}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\begin{tabular}{| L{4.5cm} | C{1.8cm} | C{1.8cm} | C{1.8cm} | D{1.8cm} |}
\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\bfseries Scores}  \\ \hline
& {\centering} {\bfseries 1988} & {\centering} {\bfseries 1989} & {\centering} {\bfseries 1990} & {\centering} {\bfseries Change} \\ \hline
{\bfseries Overall}  & {\bfseries 234} & {\bfseries 218} & {\bfseries 198} & {\bfseries-36}   \\ \hline
Sub Score 1 & 262 & 257 & 253 & -9   \\ \hline
Sub Score 2 & 227 & 214 & 196 & -31   \\ \hline
Sub Score 3 & 187 & 188 & 353 & +166   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{siunitx}` in the preamble and then replace the D{1.8cm} with `>{\columncolor{LightDandelion}}S[table-format=4.]`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I just put the entries from the last column into a right-justified fixed-width box via the macro defined as `\rjust`.  The width of the box I have hardwired as the widest element of the column, in this case `+166`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{calc}

\definecolor{LightDandelion}{RGB}{255,255,204}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{LightDandelion}}m{#1}}
\newcommand\rjust[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\mdseries+166}][r]{#1}}
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{0pt}}
\begin{table}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\begin{tabular}{| L{4.5cm} | C{1.8cm} | C{1.8cm} | C{1.8cm} | D{1.8cm} |}
\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\bfseries Scores}  \\ \hline
& {\centering} {\bfseries 1988} & {\centering} {\bfseries 1989} & {\centering} {\bfseries 1990} & {\centering} {\bfseries Change} \\ \hline
{\bfseries Overall}  & {\bfseries 234} & {\bfseries 218} & {\bfseries 198} & {\bfseries\rjust{$-$36}}   \\ \hline
Sub Score 1 & 262 & 257 & 253 & \rjust{$-$9}   \\ \hline
Sub Score 2 & 227 & 214 & 196 & \rjust{$-$31}   \\ \hline
Sub Score 3 & 187 & 188 & 353 & \rjust{+166}   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `$-$9` and not `$-9$`? (Not really a big deal, I know.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Didn't matter in this case, I suppose, but in case someone had the math numerals distinctly defined from the text numerals...